# Adding a <div> block messes up the rest of the page

Tags: css, layout, html

I am editing a forum layout consisting of a left-side wide area and a right-side narrow sidebar.  The left-side area also has content blocks attached at the bottom.  I am trying to add additional  blocks to the sidebar, but that messes up the bottom content blocks on the left side.

This is the code I'm adding:

```
<div class="rt-block>
<div class="module-surround">
<div style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
      My content
</div></div></div>
```

I am simply cloning existing elements already present in the sidebar and adding an extra box, and it's breaking the left side.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Div by default is display: block, that means, it renders the next element on the next line.

you need to provide float: left if there are floating elements (showing multiple elements on the same line. )

Comment: Pretty much impossible to help here without seeing more html/css. Please consider creating a jsfiddle showing the problem or provide a link to your site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't closing the quotes on `<div class="rt-block>`

Comment: Wow, it was a missing quotation mark.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, these things are very easily missed.